# Navision: Import CSV File Report vs XML Port vs CU

Tags: report, navision, cal

I just wander why some some developers use Report, some uses CU and others uses XML Port to import a CSV file. I know you can achieve this using anyone of those object!

But I just wander why most people do it using a report object? any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that the majority would use an XMLPort to import CSV's.
Doing this via a Report object requires you to worry about splitting the incoming line by your chosen field delimiter (,) and then also worrying about text delimiters (").
An XMLPort can support this automatically via the properties.

Comment: I agree, Importing CSV's is done through dataports in old versions (Classic Until 2009 R2) and XML-ports  in newer Versions (RTC from 2009).